# Is wxpython progressdialog cancel event possible?

Tags: python, wxpython

if I declare wxProgressDialog with wxPD_CAN_ABORT, "Cancel" button will be provided in ProgressDialog. Normally, to know if user pressed "Cancel", wxProgressDialog::Update needs to be called.

Is there a way to get an event, if "Cancel" is pressed in wxProgressDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by defining a custom Dialog instead of the stock ProgressDialog:

```
class MyProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, text=''):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(200,150), style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, text)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, -1)
        self.closebutton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLOSE)
        self.closebutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 0 , wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.gauge, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.Add(self.closebutton, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy() 
        #can add stuff here to do in parent.
```

You can then do updates on the progress bar by calling MyProgressDialog.gauge.Update, and have your event bound to the close button.

Comment: ok, thanks, it works. I was hoping to use ProgressDialog, but I didn't know about gauge before.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.9.1 of wx you can just use `ProgressDialog.WasCancelled()`

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GenericProgressDialog.html#wx-genericprogressdialog